# Have been waiting for the seat belt part without any ETA for more than 10 months now

Tags: consumer-protection, accident, car-insurance, automotive

I got into a minor accident last year. My car is at the repair shop ever since. All the repair work is complete except for the seat belt part. The repair shop has placed an order with the dealership. The repair shop is waiting for the seat belt part and won't release the car until they fix it completely. Apparently, they will be liable if anything happens.
I have been waiting for the part for the last 6 months. Let alone the seat belt, the car company fails to provide any ETA. My car is quite new, I bought the car in 2021. I am paying EMIs, insurance the car value is depreciating.
I reached out to the car company through all possible mediums. They refused to give me a loaner car. They ask me to talk to the dealership for any kind of help and when I go to the dealership they ask me to talk to the car company. No one is helping me out.
I filed a complaint against the company with Better Business Bureau but they didn't respond to BBB.
I am just trying to find out if I can pursue any legal options here. Do I even have a case against the dealership of the car company?

Comment: Why does a minor accident need a seat belt part?

Comment: The impact was close to the sensor so the airbag was deployed and the seat belt got locked.

Comment: What is the difference between "repair shop", "car company", "dealership" and "the company"? Why isn't your insurance company finding a solution? Are *they* providing a temporary car?

Comment: After the accident, I towed my car to a local repair shop. They have placed an order with the local car dealership. The dealership in turn has placed the order with the car company (aka make or brand). The dealership says that there is a national backorder for the seat belt part for this Car company and they don't have any control over the part supply.

Comment: "I towed my car to a local repair shop" so it wasn't "a minor accident". Who's fault was it? Was the repair shop recommended by the insurance company? Is this a thicket of your own making? Sorry you are in such a tangle.

Comment: Yeah, I meant there was no physical damage. It was other party’s fault but they don’t have an insurance. Yes, the repair shop was suggested by the insurance. What is a thicket?

Answer (score 6):

### This would appear to violate Consumer Guarantees under the Australian Consumer Law

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

One of the statutory [guarantees](https://www.accc.gov.au/consumers/buying-products-and-services/consumer-rights-and-guarantees#:%7E:text=When%20a%20consumer%20buys%20a,from%20the%20manufacturer%20or%20importer.) is that spare parts and repairs must be available for a reasonable time after purchase.

Breach of a guarantee entitles the consumer to compensation for their losses.

Comment: This strikes me as a protection against the manufacturer ceasing the production and distribution of spare parts altogether; the linked page says nothing to suggest that it would apply to (transient) problems in the manufacturer's supply chain.